# some verd problems in qt

Tags: windows, qt

I am very new to qt, So whatever I facing is either errors or problems. Here goes some of them,

1)Just try to install it in VisualStudio, you will got enough for the day.

2)After you installed it as a separate qt(without embedding it inside visual studio).Open a c++ file in qt, => then you won't get any option to compile it.

3)Create a empty qt4 project like below

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int a,char * argv[])
{

}
```

Then build it, you will get a error like this

```
C:\qt-greenhouse\Trolltech\Code_less_create_more\Trolltech\Code_less_create_more\Troll\4.6\qt\src\winmain/qtmain_win.cpp:131: undefined reference to `qMain(int, char**)'
```

Can anybody clear any of these problems to me.

Comment: It's probably a build system issue, your code looks ok. How does your .pro file (if you use qmake) look like? You can create one with "qmake -project" (on the CLI, don't know about visual studio).

Comment: I tried hard to embed the qt into visual studio, but I never succeed. I frustrated.

Comment: Did you mean "weird problems"? What is "verd"?

Answer (score 0):

Is this really all you are including?

Seems like some header is interfering with the main definition (like SDL_main.h or something).

Comment: but i didn't include anything except the basic iostream, but the error stays as it is

Comment: maybe the Qt make environment did

Comment: Did anyone got any problem like this

Comment: This is recent, I tried to make a statically compiled application in Qt. So from the resource, I came to know that I have to go to that directory through VS2008 command prompt, and type (1)configure -static(2)nmake. Tt took more than 6 hours, including the download and configure it took around 9 hours. At last exited with failure, stating that there is no enough space. And the space It took during installation is 17GB!!!!!!!!!!!.